# Whats the best way to refactor code that news up a POCO class

Tags: c#, .net, solid-principles

In work I was asked to fix a bug which involved me making changes in a class. To fix the bug I needed to add a collection of a class that looks like this.

```
public class Branch
{
    public int StartNode { get; set; }
    
    public int EndNode { get; set; }
}
```

The collection

```
List<Branch> _vistedBranch = new List<Branch>();
```

My concern is I was always taught to hate seeing "new" in any of my classes as it tightly couples my class to other classes. However this class is just a POCO class that doesn't have any functionality. I am just using it in the class I am working on to store a collection of start nodes and end nodes.

This is how I have used it in the class

```
public class CustomerCountRequestProcessor : ICustomerCountRequestProcessor
{
    List<Branch> _vistedBranch = new List<Branch>();
    private INetwork _network;
    public CustomerCountRequestProcessor(INetwork network)
    {
        _network = network ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(network));
    }

    public int GetCustomersForSelectedNode(IRoot request)
    {
        if (request == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));

        _network = request.Network;
        return ProcessSelectedNode(request.SelectedNode);
    }

    private int ProcessSelectedNode(int node)
    {
        var nc = _network.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Node == node);
        var customersForNode = nc != null ? nc.NumberOfCustomers : 0;

        foreach (var subNode in _network.Branches.Where(b => b.StartNode == node))
        {
            bool has = _vistedBranch.Any(b => b.StartNode == subNode.StartNode
                && b.EndNode == subNode.EndNode);
            if (has)
            { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); }
            _vistedBranch.Add(new Branch()
            {
                StartNode = subNode.StartNode,
                EndNode = subNode.EndNode
            });
            customersForNode += ProcessSelectedNode(subNode.EndNode);
        }

        return customersForNode;
    }
}
```

So my question is simple, how would I refactor that collection to make my code more clean.

1. Do I make a class out of the collection. Then make an interface out of the class then bring it in using dependency injection?
   2.Do I make a factory class, stick that collection in there and then new up the factory when I need the class?
   These  options above seem a lot of code for one simple POCO class.
   Maybe its just as simple as putting the new part into the constructor like this.

```
List<Branch> _vistedBranch;
private INetwork _network;
public CustomerCountRequestProcessor(INetwork network)
{
    _vistedBranch = new List<Branch>();
    _network = network ??
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(network));
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Since you already have some working code, the [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site would be a better fit.

Comment: A `HashSet<T>` will fit better here.

Comment: `Branch` is a data class. This question is typically asked as "_Does dependency inversion apply to data classes?_" And the answer is typically, "_no._" Feel free to `new` up all the data you need in local variables. Just keep the concrete references out of your API.

Answer (score 0):

Go with 1.
and a constructer would also be pretty good

Comment: These questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, so it's best not to answer them, and instead refer contributors to e.g. Code Review Stack Exchange (as @imsmn has done in the comments). That said, even if this was on-topic, or if it were on Code Review Stack Exchange, we'd expect more explanation of _why_ these options are preferred, instead of simply an assertion.